# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col' error

Tags: python, pandas

First 2 rows of loop works but last row df[col] gives error. I get 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col' error

```
   df = pd.DataFrame([(.2, np.nan,), (.0, .6, 2), (.6, .0, 1), (.2, .1, 1 )],
                  columns=['dogs', 'cats','monkeys'])

corr=df.corr(method='pearson')

for col in corr.columns:
    print ('col:', col)
    print(df[col])
    df[col]=df[col].fillna(corr.col.mean())
```

Comment: `corr.col.mean()` should probably be `corr[col].mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[col]` for select column by variable:

```
for col in corr.columns:
    print ('col:', col)
    print(df[col])
    df[col]=df[col].fillna(corr[col].mean())
```

Better and simplier solution is pass `mean` to [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) :

```
df = df.fillna(df.corr(method='pearson').mean())
```